# Vue rendering only part of my App.vue after a login

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am working on a Vue.js application that I am almost done, one major bug left. The bug/issue is that when you go to /login and login to the site you get redirected via a router push (tried replace too) and when this happens I want to render the whole dashboard. Currently since in my App.vue file the router view is a different part it only renders the dashboard info part and not my header or sidebar.

Pretty much imagine a dashboard without a header or sidebar. That's what's rendering. I'd be okay if I could do something like `F5` does because then it all would load correctly though taking up to 2 seconds longer on login which is okay by me.

My App.vue file template code

```
<template>
    <div class="fade page-sidebar-fixed page-header-fixed show page-container" v-if="!pageOptions.pageEmpty" v-bind:class="{ 
        'page-sidebar-minified': pageOptions.pageSidebarMinified, 
        'page-content-full-height': pageOptions.pageContentFullHeight, 
        'page-with-top-menu': pageOptions.pageWithTopMenu,
        'page-sidebar-toggled': pageOptions.pageMobileSidebarToggled,
        'has-scroll': pageOptions.pageBodyScrollTop
    }">
        <Header />
        <Sidebar v-if="!pageOptions.pageWithoutSidebar" />
        <div id="content" class="content" v-bind:class="{ 'content-full-width': pageOptions.pageContentFullWidth, 'content-inverse-mode': pageOptions.pageContentInverseMode }">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: One of reasons may be wrong structure of routes, so dashboard is rendering into router view in v-else block.

Comment: You are sorta right, so it is rendering into that though I'm not sure how to make sure only certain pages go to the else, the if pretty much checks a config file. If I remove the if and comment the else out it shows the header/sidebar for all pages including login which I don't want. Not sure what you mean by the routes are wrong? They all work as expected, it's the view that's the issue.

Comment: I think the best way is to make structure as I mentioned in my answer. The key idea is to have base views and render everything else inside them. It is not dificult to change your project to follow this way. But still it is up to you.

Comment: @TimurGilauri See my answer, the solution was way simpler than doing a massive refactor. I like simple and effective solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I have resolved my issue, it comes from vue-router and how I am doing that if statement in my template code. So in that code I am checking a boolean value then choosing which view to render. So I had though on all of my auth pages I set the value correctly on exit. Turns out not...

This was in my Login.vue file, idea was to have on an exit of the route that it would change the boolean to false which would let me render it right. This was something I did initally but had forgotten about till about 20 minutes ago.

Upon checking this I found the value was not being changed for some reason. So as a work around in the `created` part of my Dashboard.vue file I set the value to false explicitly

Login.vue

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    PageOptions.pageEmpty = false;
    next();
},
```

Dashboard.vue

```
created() {
    PageOptions.pageEmpty = false;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to have several base pages each one of them is operate with its own set of internal views.

You have to redirect user to another view, which is the one and only active view and this view can contains sidebar header and main part that also contains router-view, and then! you load any needed components in it.

You have to have something like that:

[image: Project structure]

App component is only contains router view tag and any other pages are load into this.

[image]

The routes structure then looks like that:

[image: the routes]

As you can see, there are two base views load in App view. And then the base view can has  a lot of children. The level of nested routes is up to you. Here is the contents of my app Home view:

[image: The Home component content]

And the MainContent component which is contains router view only:

[image: The MainContent component content]

The good example of project structure is the one generated with vue-cli. You can use it to simplify dev process with a lot of benefits and good practice solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep looking for a solution. Your method has me repeating code, doing major refactor, and rerendering things I don't want to rerender since that would increase load on my server and I don't want an increased AWS bill

BTW I use the CLI tool, pretty sure just about everyone does

Comment: Looking more at your code I see it causing the exact same issue I am having now just in a different way. It would render the application part of the dashoard not the sidebar and header on initial login. Also trying to use what I have and just modify it compared to a complete refactor of the routes and application

Comment: Looking more at what you have there compared to what I have the more rewriting I think I would have to do. I am looking to launch this project soon so a complete Vue router rewrite and template code refactor, isn't in the cards. I need a solution that works with what I have.